# Ubuntu shell: Get tomorrow's weekday

Tags: ubuntu, shell-scripting, date

I have a shell script for backups and I need the Weekday of tomorrow.

```
$Today = $(date +%a)
#$Tomorrow = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ date +%a --date="tomorrow"
Thu
```

Comment: @Martin - by the way, I didn't know this previously, but the answer was in the first link for a google search for "linux date tomorrow".